# Ort::Session.run() Exception when running inference on CUDA

Tags: c++, deep-learning, pytorch, onnxruntime

I am trying to run the inference on my Nvidia GPU. I have installed Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu version 1.12.0 in Visual Studio 2019 using NuGet package manager.

Cuda Version 11.3.

I get exception: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF94A23A48 (cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll)
session.Run(runOptions, inputNames.data(), &inputTensor, 1, outputNames.data(), &outputTensor, 1);

When I run the inference on CPU it works fine.

`Ort::SessionOptions ort_session_options; OrtCUDAProviderOptions options; options.device_id = 0; OrtSessionOptionsAppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(ort_session_options, options.device_id); . . . . session.Run(runOptions, inputNames.data(), &inputTensor, 1, outputNames.data(), &outputTensor, 1);`

I am using:

ONNX Runtime Version
1.12

ONNX Runtime API
C++

Architecture
X64

Execution Provider
CUDA

Execution Provider Library Version
CUDA 11.3

I have tried with different versions of Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu version and was not able to run the inference on GPU.